# How to be explicit about negative sampling for Link prediction using GNN?

Tags: python, sampling, graph-neural-network

Regarding recommendation systems of bi-partite graphs with PyTorch geometric, most of the tutorials I found about Link prediction using GNNs suggest using negative sampling in an (I guess) random way.

So, when I'm splitting my dataset, I can include some random negative samples in my training data using the following code:

```py
transform = T.RandomLinkSplit(
    num_val=0.1,
    num_test=0.1,
    disjoint_train_ratio=0.3,
    neg_sampling_ratio=2.0,
    add_negative_train_samples=True,
    edge_types=("user", "rates", "movie"),
    rev_edge_types=("movie", "rev_rates", "user"), 
)
train_data, val_data, test_data = transform(data)
```

This will introduce 2:1 negative samples in my training data.

If instead of including negative samples in my training, I can include them in the validation dataset using the loader with code similar as (changing the line of previous code `add_negative_train_samples=False`):

```py
val_loader = LinkNeighborLoader(
    data=val_data,
    num_neighbors=[20, 10],
    neg_sampling_ratio=2.0,
    edge_label_index=(("user", "rates", "movie"), edge_label_index),
    edge_label=edge_label,
    batch_size=3 * 128,
    shuffle=False,
)
```

**My question is**: How can I be explicit about my negative samples? I know that if I know the connected AND the not connected nodes in my original dataset, maybe I don't need to use a GNN to predict, but what should I do when I know some of them?